# Update permission in vue-acl

Tags: laravel, vue.js, permissions, acl

I implemented vue-acl it works but when i update the permission then my menus are not hide & showing instantly as per permission on frontend.

There are only single role but i have add, edit, delete, view permission for all menu. when i update these permission then vue reactive property is not working.

Its working after manual refresh of the page.

& once i manually refresh the page then acl.js file is calling , i add this path in main.js as well.

This may be because after updating the permission, vue acl instance is not updating, also global rules are not updating.

I try a lot from past 2 days but not found any help.

my acl.js file like

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { AclInstaller, AclCreate, AclRule } from 'vue-acl'
import router from '@/router'
Vue.use(AclInstaller)  
let initialRole = 'admin'
let permissionarray = null;
const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
if (userInfo && userInfo.userRole) initialRole = userInfo.userRole
if (userInfo && userInfo.permissions) permissionarray = userInfo.permissions
const rolePermissions = {}

// Default Permission
rolePermissions[initialRole] = new AclRule(initialRole).generate()
rolePermissions['default'] = new AclRule('default').or(initialRole).generate()
// Roles Permission
for (var key in permissionarray) {
    for(var key2 in permissionarray[key])
    {
        if(permissionarray[key][key2] == true){
            rolePermissions[key+'_'+key2] = new AclRule(key+'_'+key2).or(initialRole).generate()
        }else{
            rolePermissions[key+'_'+key2] = new AclRule(key+'_'+key2).generate()
        }
    }
}
//console.log(rolePermissions);
export default new AclCreate({
  initial  : initialRole,
  notfound : '/error-403',
  router,
  acceptLocalRules : true,
  globalRules: rolePermissions,
})
```

my main.js file like
File Name: main.js
Description: main vue(js) file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

// Vuesax Component Framework
import Vuesax from 'vuesax'

Vue.use(Vuesax) 

// axios
import axios from './axios.js'
Vue.prototype.$http = axios


// Theme Configurations
import '../themeConfig.js'
 

// Globally Registered Components
import './globalComponents.js'

// Vue Router
import router from './router'


// Vuex Store
import store from './store/store'

// Vuexy Admin Filters
import './filters/filters'

import interceptorsSetup from './helpers/interceptors'
interceptorsSetup()


// VeeValidate
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
Vue.use(VeeValidate)

import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    // Add your API key here
    key: 'xyz',
    libraries: 'places' // This is required if you use the Auto complete plug-in
  }
})

// Vuejs - Vue wrapper for hammerjs
import { VueHammer } from 'vue2-hammer'
Vue.use(VueHammer)


// PrismJS
import 'prismjs'
import 'prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css'

// ACL
import acl from './acl/acl'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
 

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  acl,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

can you show how did you implement your rules update?
I was facing the same problem.
So I decide to manage the rules by Store ( vuex )
I'm using VUEXY template, so in my store, I did insert this code `this._vm.$acl.change(user_permissions_array)`.
Then you will can check and validate the permissions inside all components with
`$acl.check('your_rule_string')` or `$acl.get.indexOf('your_rule_string') > -1`
I hope it can help you.